# C++ memory leak with managed C++ using CRT library - _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks() issues

Tags: c#, c++, memory-leaks

I try to get program memory leaks using the MSDN CRT Library, but get an anormal issue while launching _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks() because it never ends the execution of the thread.

Structure :
nUnit Test that intiates a DLL wrapped class that just calls _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()... The debugger runs for a while (process activity) then hangs but doesn't stop - no more activity.

The new, malloc, calloc, realloc and free functions have been overwritten as saied in MSDN documentation.

What am I missing ?

My context :
Visual Studio 2012 Update 5, Managed C++ (C++/CLI), Unit Test C# (nUnit)

Comment: Show us the codez.  [ask]

Comment: Probably you have a bad case of memory corruption... Try executing it at the start of the program and in various moments of the program. Clearly you'll see many leaks (because there are many objects that are still referenced), but at least you'll be able to pinpoint the corruption

Comment: Corrected as you suggest. OK. I go through out the dump...

But here is the code :

 char * memLeak = (char *) malloc(64);
 memset(memLeak,0,64);
 _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();

I get no memory leaks !

Normal ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a part of the first lines

```
char * memLeak = (char *) malloc(64);
memset(memLeak,0,64);
_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
```

With xanatos help, _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks() finally runs...

But returns nothing !
I attend to get the memLeak variable shown as memory Leak.